# Каким образом реализовать, чтобы при отключении наушников выключался плеер?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app, headset

Здравствуйте.

Как сделать так, что бы при отключении наушников выключалось радио(плеер), то есть ставилась пауза?

Где и что прописывается?

Возможно нужно мне показать содержание какого либо файла (**.class** или **.xml**) вам, чтобы узнать, как это реализовать?

Я просто не совсем понял, каким образом это происходить должно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого есть специальное событие, о котором уведомляет система. "Поймать" его можно с помощью так называемых Broadcast Reciever'ов. Вот код, который показывает, как узнать о подключении/отключении наушников:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
  private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
  private MusicIntentReceiver myReceiver;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myReceiver = new MusicIntentReceiver();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume(){ 
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    super.onResume(); 
  }


  private class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
      if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
        switch (state) { 
          case 0: Log.d(TAG, "Наушники отключены"); break; 
          case 1: Log.d(TAG, "Наушники подключены"); break; 
          default: Log.d(TAG, "Неизвестное состояние"); 
        } 
      }
    }
  } 

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    super.onPause(); 
  }
}
```

Источник:
  [Официальная документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)

Comment: мне создавать новый класс  нужно? или это вписывается в главное активити приложения? У меня есть просто уже класс NotificationBroadcast, судя по логике нужно и в этой ситуации создать новый класс, да?

Comment: Зависит от вашей ситуации и от того, что должно происходить при этом действии. Это может быть вложенный в MainActivity класс, как я показал в примере. Однако если подразумевается достаточно большое количество кода, то можно сделать и отдельным классом. Если будете делать отдельным классом, то не забудьте добавить Receiver в манифест приложения

Comment: Также если не изменяет память, можно зарегистрировать несколько Intent фильтров на один объект. Тогда можно не создавать новый класс, а использовать существующий.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо обработать системное событие AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY, которое возникает при переключении аудио выхода обратно на встроенный динамик при отключении любых гарнитур. Подробнее можно ознакомится по ссылке:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones

И еще не забудьте добавить в AndroidManifest.xml строчку для вашего BroadcastReceiver:
android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY"
либо
filter.addAction(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);

Дополнительно - как правильно реализовать BroadcastReceiver:
https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/161-urok-96-service-obratnaja-svjaz-s-pomoschju-broadcastreceiver.html

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).